# Only display OpenLayers map on event

Tags: openlayers, html

I have an OpenLayers map that I only want to show when I click a button.
Initially it should be hidden.

The following code works but requires me to press F12, presumably to re-render the map after clicking the button. Working example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/dudbbKQF8sfCfRiD

How can I display the map o button click without having to press F12 for rendering?

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Simple Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.6.5/ol-debug.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.5.0/proj4.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.6.5/ol-debug.js"> </script>

  <style>
            .map1 { width: 100%;    height: auto;   border:1px solid red;   }
        .ali{   color:red;  font-size:16px; }
          .map {    height: 500px;  width: 100%;    }
  </style>
   <script type="module">

        proj4.defs('EPSG:32640', '+proj=utm +zone=40 +datum=WGS84 +units=m+no_defs')

        let options = {};
        options.code = 'EPSG:32640';
        options.units = 'm';

        options.extent = [
            -98570.85212537996, 2468701.5790765425,
            683268.1076887846,  2874585.9453238174,
        ];

        options.worldExtent = [];
        options.axisOrientation = 'enu';
        options.global = false;

        //options.metersPerUnit = projectionOptions.metersPerUnit;
        options.getPointResolution = ()=>{};

        let projection = new ol.proj.Projection(options);
        //ol.proj.addProjection(projection);
        //let ext=ol.proj.get('EPSG:32640').getExtent();
        debugger;
        //let center= ol.extent.getCenter(ext);
        var olview = new ol.View({
            center: [312234.8270497762, 2636116.2213047906],
            extent:options.extent,
            projection: 'EPSG:32640',
            zoom: 8,
        });
        
        var map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.OSM(),
                }),
            ],
            target: 'mapOL',
            view: olview,
            });
            
  </script>
  
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";          
            var x = document.getElementById("mapOL");
            if (x.style.display === "none") {               
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "here 1";
                x.style.display = "block";
                map.updateSize();
                map.resize();   map.updateSize();           
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
  </script>    
</head>
<body>
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <div id="mapOL" class="map1" style="display: none;"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have coded it the `map` variable is not in scope of the `myFunction` so the `updateSize()` call does not work.  You could give the button an id then use a single script and set the click listener in the code.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Simple Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.6.5/ol-debug.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.5.0/proj4.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.6.5/ol-debug.js"> </script>

  <style>
            .map1 { width: 100%;    height: auto;   border:1px solid red;   }
        .ali{   color:red;  font-size:16px; }
          .map {    height: 500px;  width: 100%;    }
  </style>
   <script type="module">

        proj4.defs('EPSG:32640', '+proj=utm +zone=40 +datum=WGS84 +units=m+no_defs')

        let options = {};
        options.code = 'EPSG:32640';
        options.units = 'm';

        options.extent = [
            -98570.85212537996, 2468701.5790765425,
            683268.1076887846,  2874585.9453238174,
        ];

        options.worldExtent = [];
        options.axisOrientation = 'enu';
        options.global = false;

        //options.metersPerUnit = projectionOptions.metersPerUnit;
        options.getPointResolution = ()=>{};

        let projection = new ol.proj.Projection(options);
        //ol.proj.addProjection(projection);
        //let ext=ol.proj.get('EPSG:32640').getExtent();
        debugger;
        //let center= ol.extent.getCenter(ext);
        var olview = new ol.View({
            center: [312234.8270497762, 2636116.2213047906],
            extent:options.extent,
            projection: 'EPSG:32640',
            zoom: 8,
        });
        
        var map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.OSM(),
                }),
            ],
            target: 'mapOL',
            view: olview,
            });
            
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";          
            var x = document.getElementById("mapOL");
            if (x.style.display === "none") {               
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "here 1";
                x.style.display = "block";
                map.updateSize();
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("myFunction").onclick = myFunction;
  </script>    
</head>
<body>
 <button id="myFunction">Click me</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <div id="mapOL" class="map1" style="display: none;"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much - It works. This is the answer.